# call innerHTML based on a condition from jsp code in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, spring-mvc, innerhtml

I am trying to find a way to have the document.getElementById("1").innerHTML to get triggered based on a condition coming from jsp code. 
For example I have the following jsp code on the jsp page,

```
<table border="1">
<c:forEach items="${elements}" var="element">
    <tr>
        <td>${element.elementNumber}<br /> ${element.isReserved}
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Based on "element.isReserved", I need to change an element (supposedly using .innerHTML)in html. The element in html looks like the following. I have several of these elements.

```
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <div class="o-btn">
                    <a id="1" onClick="myFunction(this);">1</a>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
```

As shown above, it is displayed as a button with value "1". I want to change the value to "X" based on a condition. I can do this directly with js,

```
<script>
        function myFunction(elmnt) {}
        function isReserved() {
            return 'X';
        }
        document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = isReserved();
</script>
```

But I need to make it dependent on the output from spring or the jsp code shown above. My desired output is that the "1" displayed on the button will change to a "X" when the element.isReserved() (inside the jsp code) evaluates to true. Since I have several of the button elements, I need to check for every button if element.isReserved() evaluates to true.

Comment: what do you mean by "Based on element.isReserved, I need to change an element in html."? what is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work. I found this [article](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html) very helpful.

After understanding (and accepting reality) how JSP works with html, I had to slightly restructure my program.

From spring mvc, I added my variables to the model,

```
model.addAttribute("element1", 1);
```

On the jsp page I checked the variables with javascript,

```
if("${element1}" == 1) {
    document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = 'X';
    document.getElementById("1").style.color = 'red';
}
```

Probably there are better solutions, but for a newbie like me, it works great!

The [article](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html) I mentioned above is indeed a good and **important** read for new comers.